# trying to save a dataframe into oracle database dtype np.dtype giving valueerror

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, dtype

i am trying to save a large dataframe to a database :

```
chunk.to_sql("xxxx".lower(),engine,if_exists='replace', dtype = {'model_id': String(80), 'EFF_DT': DateTime(), 'FACTOR_TYP':  String(80)
        , 'FACTOR_ID': String(40), 'RETURN': String(40) })
```

it gives me error :
MODEL_ID (VARCHAR(80)) not a string

as it is considering it as np.dtype. 
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this and it´s working fine with Oracle

```
df.to_sql('mytable', conn, if_exists='replace', index=True,dtype={'NAME': types.VARCHAR(df.NAME.str.len().max())})
```

Hope it helps